# Let's team up, work together, moderate together!

Tags: discussion, moderation

As some (many?) of you have read it, there's a lot going on about SE network, staff, users, and moderators. Let me be really clear on this one: I'm not pointing fingers or taking any side. This is **NOT** about discussing and arguing about who's right or wrong.

But, as the *** might hit the fan, and *because* it may hit the fan, I think that it's time to be, more than ever, a community, and work as a team. We must stick together, and help each other.

Let's take some weight off our mods' shoulders by using our tools and powers to lighten the burden. They may or may not need more help, let's just be ready to handle more of the workload.

Support our community :)

Comment: Thank you for the encouraging post, I appreciate the sentiment! (And just in case anyone reads this and gets alarmed: it's been a regular Monday so far on this site :)) IPS has a pretty great community and I'm honored to handle your flags :D

Comment: "They may or may not need more help" -> we're always more than happy to see community moderators shape the community! We're here to help with urgent matters but **you** make the community, and I'm so glad you do.

Answer (score 8):

I absolutely love this sentiment. [Like I said in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51902486#51902486), I'm here because of the community--and that community is made up of all of you lovely IPS users!

I know there's been talks about [going on strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334026/232439) with moderation, but whether you fall on the strike side or you're with OldPadawan on the "let's help out more to show our appreciation to our mods!" side or maybe somewhere in between, **I only ask that you remember the reason we're all here together--each other!**

If you decide to stop moderating, that's fine. If you decide to take a break from the site, that's fine. But regardless of what you choose to do, let's keep an open mind and accept each other's views on this tough situation. **No matter what happens, let's not let this affect how we treat each other.**

From what I've seen so far, we've been handling this well and I know that we'll continue to do so. Stay strong guys!<3

Comment: There was a similar call for action in WPS (which I think is the most severely affected SE I'm part of) for the community to act as a "community watch" even more than usual.

Comment: I almost wrote this exact same post yesterday (even had a link to your comment in chat), but I couldn't find the right words. I know that emotions are running high across the network and a lot of people have been hurt. We as a community are supposed have good interpersonal skills, or at the very least be very intentional about striving to have good interpersonal skills. If ever there was a time where this community can exemplify the notion that interpersonal skills are what we use to "interact ***well**" with others, the time is now.